# Calculate and output the date of customer's first order

Tags: r

Data:

```
DB <- data.frame(orderID = c(1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7,8),    
                 orderDate = c("1.1.12","1.1.12","1.1.12","13.1.12","13.1.12","12.1.12","10.1.12","10.1.12","21.1.12","24.1.12"),
                 itemID = c(2,3,2,5,12,4,2,3,1,5),   
                 customerID = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1),
                 itemPrice = c(9.99, 14.99, 9.99, 19.99, 29.99, 4.99, 9.99, 14.99, 49.99, 19.99))
```

Expected outcome:

```
DB <- data.frame(orderID = c(1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7,8),    
                 orderDate = c("1.1.12","2.1.12","3.1.12","13.1.12","13.1.12","12.1.12","10.1.12","10.1.12","21.1.12","24.1.12"),
                 itemID = c(2,3,2,5,12,4,2,3,1,5),   
                 customerID = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1),
                 itemPrice = c(9.99, 14.99, 9.99, 19.99, 29.99, 4.99, 9.99, 14.99, 49.99, 19.99),
                 DateOfFirstOrderofCustomer = c("1.1.12", "2.1.12", "3.1.12", "1.1.12", "1.1.12", "3.1.12", "2.1.12", "2.1.12", "1.1.12", "1.1.12"))
```

For Understanding:

The `orderI`D is continuous. Products orderd from the same `customerID` at the same day get the same `orderID`. When the same customer orders products at another day he/she it´s a new `orderID`.

I want to add an additional column for every row/entry which contains the date of the customer's first order (e.g. customer 1 (`customerID` 1) made his first order on `1.1.12` so this date is entered in all orders from this customer). How can we do this?

The original data has about 500k rows: so plz give a solution which needs only little perfomance.

Comment: Your `orderDate` from data and expected outcome don't match. Hopefully my answer solves this by including dummy data.

Comment: That´s right - my mistake :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With just base R functions:

```
# convert the date column to date-format
DB$orderDate <- as.Date(DB$orderDate, format('%d.%m.%y'))

# get the first date for each customer
DB$DateFirstOrder <- with(DB, ave(orderDate, customerID, FUN = min))
```

the result is then (using the data of Mike Spencer):

```
> DB
   orderID  orderDate itemID customerID itemPrice DateFirstOrder
1        1 2012-01-01      2          1      9.99     2012-01-01
2        2 2012-01-04      3          2     14.99     2012-01-04
3        3 2012-01-06      2          3      9.99     2012-01-06
4        4 2012-01-13      5          1     19.99     2012-01-01
5        4 2012-01-13     12          1     29.99     2012-01-01
6        5 2012-01-12      4          3      4.99     2012-01-06
7        6 2012-01-10      2          2      9.99     2012-01-04
8        6 2012-01-10      3          2     14.99     2012-01-04
9        7 2012-01-21      1          1     49.99     2012-01-01
10       8 2012-01-24      5          1     19.99     2012-01-01
```

---

For the fastest solution, I would recommend the **data.table** package. To get the desired result with this package, you need to do:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DB)[, orderDate := as.Date(orderDate, format('%d.%m.%y'))
          ][, DateFirstOrder := min(orderDate), by = customerID]
```

Comment: Thank´s a lot for your support! I can´t check if it works today: will check tomorrow morning and give you a feedback.

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner Glad I could help, you can let me know if you have follow-up questions.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your input data as those you provided all had the same date of first purchase from each customer, so it was impossible to tell if the code worked. The example uses dplyr, you could also use tapply, but you'd need to reformat the named vector.

```
# Dummy data
DB <- data.frame(orderID = c(1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7,8),    
                 orderDate = c("1.1.12","4.1.12","6.1.12","13.1.12","13.1.12","12.1.12","10.1.12","10.1.12","21.1.12","24.1.12"),
                 itemID = c(2,3,2,5,12,4,2,3,1,5),   
                 customerID = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1),
                 itemPrice = c(9.99, 14.99, 9.99, 19.99, 29.99, 4.99, 9.99, 14.99, 49.99, 19.99))

# -------------------------------------------

# Change dates to a readable format
DB$orderDate <- as.Date(DB$orderDate, format="%d.%m.%y")

# -------------------------------------------

library(dplyr)

DB <- DB %>% 
   group_by(customerID) %>% 
   mutate(DateOfFirstOrderofCustomer=min(orderDate))
```

Comment: Thank´s a lot for your support! I can´t check if it works today: will check tomorrow morning and give you a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `plyr` package. rest everything is same.

```
DB <- data.frame(orderID = c(1,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,7,8),    
             orderDate = c("1.1.12","4.1.12","6.1.12","13.1.12","13.1.12","12.1.12","10.1.12","10.1.12","21.1.12","24.1.12"),
             itemID = c(2,3,2,5,12,4,2,3,1,5),   
             customerID = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1),
             itemPrice = c(9.99, 14.99, 9.99, 19.99, 29.99, 4.99, 9.99, 14.99, 49.99, 19.99))


install.packages("plyr")
library(plyr)

DB$orderDate <- as.Date(DB$orderDate, format="%d.%m.%y")
DB = ddply(DB, .(customerID), mutate, DateOfFirstOrderofCustomer = min(orderDate))
```

Comment: Thank´s a lot for your support! I can´t check if it works today: will check tomorrow morning and give you a feedback.