# Using Apply instead of for (using 2 columns of a data frame)

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I have a data frame like this:

```
 Letters      Dates
       A 22/03/2015
       A 22/03/2015
       A 23/03/2015
       B 22/03/2015
       B 23/03/2015
       C 23/03/2015
       C 23/03/2015
```

I'd like to create another column (Dates2) which assigns at each row the minimum date of all the rows with that letter. This is the result:

```
Letters      Dates     Dates2
      A 22/03/2015 22/03/2015
      A 22/03/2015 22/03/2015
      A 23/03/2015 22/03/2015
      B 22/03/2015 22/03/2015
      B 23/03/2015 22/03/2015
      C 23/03/2015 23/03/2015
      C 23/03/2015 23/03/2015
```

I wrote the following code with a for loop, but I'd like to do it more efficiently (working with vectors instead of loops). How can I do it with Apply / other solutions?

```
rm(list=ls())

data <- data.frame(rbind(c("A", "22/03/2015"),
                         c("A", "22/03/2015"),
                         c("A", "23/03/2015"),
                         c("B", "22/03/2015"),
                         c("B", "23/03/2015"),
                         c("C", "23/03/2015"),
                         c("C", "23/03/2015")
                        ), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

colnames(data) <- c("Letters", "Dates")

for (i in 1:nrow(data))
{
  thisLetter = data$Letters[i]
  temp = subset(data$Dates, data$Letters == thisLetter)
  min_date = min(as.Date(temp, "%d/%m/%Y"))
  data$Dates2[i] = format(min_date, "%d/%m/%Y")
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have a look at the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40329050/calculate-and-output-the-date-of-customers-first-order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table', grouped by 'Letters', `order` the rows based on 'Dates' after converting to `Date` class, get the first element of 'Dates' (`head(Dates, 1)`)  and assign (`:=`) it to create the 'Dates2' column.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[order(as.Date(Dates)), Dates2 := head(Dates,1), by = Letters]
```

---

Or `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
     group_by(Letters) %>%
     arrange(as.Date(Dates)) %>%
     mutate(Date2 = first(Dates))
```

Comment: For `dplyr`, would `min(as.Date(Dates))` work as well without `arrange`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I tested both options with some data and the second one (dplyr) is faster than the first one.

Answer (score 1):

This shall work!

```
library(plyr)
ddply(data, .(Letters), mutate, x2 = min(as.Date(Dates, format = "%d/%m/%Y")))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!